# iPhone app works fine when deployed via cable, but not when on testflight

Tags: iphone, objective-c, testflight

I have an iPhone app that takes in 2 time and then calculates a range of time between the start and end time. Example, I enter 5pm as the starting time and 6pm as the ending time, so the application will calculate and save 3 timings in the device and the 3 timings are displayed in order of
- 5pm
- 5:30pm
- 6pm

So the weird thing is that when I tested this build on device using a cable transfer, I am able to see the timings of 5pm, 5:30pm and 6pm respectively. But when I do a clean -> build and then transfer it to testflight. I see timings of 2:30am, 5:00pm and 6:00pm

Seems like somehow testflight is screwing up the binary although I can't seem to figure out why. Anyone has any clues about this issue?

Comment: Testflight can't really screw with your app, its just delivers the files. Are you sure you are putting the latest .ipa file on testflight? Its easy to mess up and give it an older archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that the most common cause for this is that there's a bug that only manifests when in 'Release' configuration. 'Debug' configuration is sometimes able to hide a bug, especially when related to memory management.

Since TestFlight will generally use 'Release' configuration, it can look like its causing the bug. See if you can reproduce the bug locally by building in 'Release configuration. If you can, you now have a faster feedback loop to diagnose the problem with log statements. (Since you'll have no debugger).

Comment: Hmm, I will try that out. This reasoning sounds plausible, thanks Jasper

Comment: Yup, somehow the issue is a Release configuration issue and does not appear in debug mode. So I am looking into the bug now. I really hate these Release/Debug mode bugs

Comment: Many Many thanks Jasper...you saved my whole project from being scrapped...heavily indebted to you mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the app from iPhone and agin ru the app via cable. This could be One reason.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the app and then download it using Testflight and the problem still persists. Is there some timezone setting that I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, bug fixed. It really was 1 of those rare bugs that do not appear in Debug configuration, but appears in Release configuration. So what I did was I did a static analysis through the code and fixed all the warnings, then the bug went away :)

Comment: Nice work. . . you can accept the answer if you found it helpful too.